# How To Create BTC Raw Transactions With 0 BTC Wallet And Broadcast It On Blockchain Network?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NFMMNXyHNE

I watched a YouTube video of someone that created several BTC raw transactions with 0 BTC Wallet and broadcasted it on blockchain network with valid transaction hash that was Visible and remained Unconfirmed for 7 to 72 hours before disappearing from the blockchain network.

How can I replicate this using Bitcoin Core? My Bitcoin Core full node is up to date.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: If you have 0 BTC, what are you going to transact with?

Comment: Visit this YouTube link and watch the video so that you can understand my question very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NFMMNXyHNE

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, and is a common scam.

The approach these scammers take is to publish a video or telegram message, like the one you've found, claiming to be able to do the impossible. They then ask you to contact them.

Once you contact them, they will provide you with a software that is apparently able to do this. Some of them may charge you for the software, some may not.

This software in turn is a lookalike of popular wallets like Bitcoin Core and electrum, and will appear to do ask you ask - however, no transaction is actually created, and nothing is broadcast.

While you try to use the software, it will search your computer for existing bitcoin and crypto wallets, before attempting to drain them, upload keys to the scammers, or installing malware to continue compromising your system.

Stay away from anyone who claims to be able to do such things, and never install or run any program or code they share with you.

Comment: The bitcoin transactions shown in the Youtube video were all unconfirmed transactions. My question is how to create raw transactions with 0 BTC and broadcast it on blockchain network that will be Visible and remained Unconfirmed for 7 to 72 hours before disappearing from the blockchain network using Bitcoin Core?

Comment: You cannot. Those videos show fake transactions to convince you to reach out to the person and ask for a program that can do this. There is no way to do this.

Comment: @RaghavSood is right on! This video is fake.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe isn't achievable.

- You cannot use funds in a transaction that don't exist or that you don't have the private key for.
- A transaction that creates new money is invalid and will not be relayed by any honest network participants.

Comment: The bitcoin transactions shown in the Youtube video were all unconfirmed transactions. My question is how to create raw transactions with 0 BTC and broadcast it on blockchain network that will be Visible and remained Unconfirmed for 7 to 72 hours before disappearing from the blockchain network using Bitcoin Core?

Comment: It's not possible, what the video is showing is fake. Invalid transactions don't show up on the Bitcoin network.

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's a scam.**

In order to construct a bitcoin transaction, you'd have to have non-0 UTXO and a private key. The invalid transaction wouldn't be available in bitcoin core mempoool. So to create it you'd have to have non-zero UTXO and privkey. 
There is no possibility that the software in the video is centralized, if the creators would use their own funds with non-zero UTXO, with zero fees, any miner could attack it by priority mining.

Comment: The bitcoin transactions shown in the Youtube video were all unconfirmed transactions. My question is how to create raw transactions with 0 BTC and broadcast it on blockchain network that will be Visible and remained Unconfirmed for 7 to 72 hours before disappearing from the blockchain network using Bitcoin Core?